# SC_THREAD does not get triggered by its sensitivity list

Tags: systemc

I am developing a simple NAND module in SystemC. By specification, it should have a 4 ns delay so I tried to describe it with a process with a "wait" statement and `SC_THREAD`, as follows:

```
//file: nand.h
#include "systemc.h"

SC_MODULE(nand2){
    sc_in<bool> A, B; 
    sc_out<bool> F; 

    void do_nand2(){
        bool a, b, f;
        a = A.read();
        b = B.read();
        f = !(a && b);
        wait(4, SC_NS);
        F.write(f);
    }

    SC_CTOR(nand2){
        SC_THREAD(do_nand2);
        sensitive << A << B;
    }
};
```

To simulate I've created another module the outputs the stimulus for the NAND, as follows:

```
//file: stim.h
#include "systemc.h"

SC_MODULE(stim){
    sc_out<bool> A, B;
    sc_in<bool> Clk;

    void stimGen(){
        wait();
        A.write(false);
        B.write(false);
        wait();
        A.write(false);
        B.write(true);
        wait();
        A.write(true);
        B.write(true);
        wait();
        A.write(true);
        B.write(false);
    }

    SC_CTOR(stim){
        SC_THREAD(stimGen);
        sensitive << Clk.pos();
    }
};
```

Having these two modules described, the top module (where `sc_main` is) looks like this:

```
//file: top.cpp    
#include "systemc.h"
#include "nand.h"
#include "stim.h"

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    sc_signal<bool> ASig, BSig, FSig;
    sc_clock Clk("Clock", 100, SC_NS, 0.5);

    stim Stim("Stimulus");
    Stim.A(ASig); Stim.B(BSig); Stim.Clk(Clk);

    nand2 nand2("nand2");
    nand2.A(ASig); nand2.B(BSig); nand2.F(FSig);

    sc_trace_file *wf = sc_create_vcd_trace_file("sim");
    sc_trace(wf, Stim.Clk, "Clock");
    sc_trace(wf, nand2.A, "A");
    sc_trace(wf, nand2.B, "B");
    sc_trace(wf, nand2.F, "F");

    sc_start(400, SC_NS);

    sc_close_vcd_trace_file(wf);

    return 0;
}
```

The code was compiled and simulated with no errors, however when visualizing the `.vcd` file in gtkwave the output (F) gets stuck in 1, only showing the delay in the beginning of the simulation.

To test if there were any errors in the code I removed the "wait" statements and changed `SC_THREAD` to `SC_METHOD` in the `nand.h` file and simulated again, now getting the correct results, but without the delays of course.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Just solved the problem:

instead of using

```
wait(4, SC_NS);
```

with `SC_THREAD` I used

```
next_trigger(4, SC_NS);
```

with `SC_METHOD` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Are you sure this works? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68098155/how-to-simulate-output-delay-using-next-trigger-in-systemc

Answer (score 2):

It's best if you use an `SC_METHOD` for process `do_nand2`, which is sensitive to the inputs. A thread usually has an infinite loop inside of it and it runs for the entire length of the simulation. A method runs only once from beginning to end when triggered. You use threads mostly for stimulus or concurrent processes and threads may, or may not be sensitive to any events.