# Timed simulation with SystemC

Tags: systemc

With reference to question [SystemC module not working with SC_THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125756/systemc-module-not-working-with-sc-thread), a timed simulation is imitated using     `next_trigger()`. As I understood from [this article](http://www.asic-world.com/systemc/systemc_time6.html), this restarts the thread after the specified time:

> `next_trigger(double, sc_time_unit)`: The process shall be triggered when specified time has elapsed.

I.e. it effectively executes the operations *after* the occurrence of this instruction after the time specified, but also executes the operations found *before* that instruction. I have the feeling that the repeated utilization of `next_trigger` within an `SC_THREAD` may result in 'glitches' in the simulation.

Q1: Is my feeling correct?

Q2: Is there another possibility to delay execution (something that suspending the thread for the given time, rather than restarting it)

Answer (score 2):

First of all next_trigger can only be used with `SC_METHOD`'s as mentioned [here](http://www.asic-world.com/systemc/systemc_time6.html):

> `next_trigger()` is used with process methods, one's which are not threads.

Here are a few pointer's in term of SystemC processes:

- `SC_METHOD`'s are processes which must complete it's execution at one pass.(e.g.: a simple function call)
  **Note:** Do not use `while(1)` loops in `SC_METHOD`'s.
- `SC_THREAD`'s are processes which are separate thread of execution, one must explicitly use `wait()` statements here to synchronize the SystemC kernel simulation. This is the place where you will mostly find `while(1)` (infinite) loops in use.

For suspending the thread for some simulation time you can use the `wait()` statement to introduce the perceived delay.

But for better understanding you need to understand the difference between static and dynamic sensitivity in SystemC refer [here](http://forums.accellera.org/topic/1210-static-and-dynamic-sensitivity/) for more information.