# How to simulate output delay using next_trigger() in SystemC?

Tags: systemc, digital-logic

I have been reading this upvoted answer on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26129960/12311164

It says that replacing `wait(delay, units);` in SC_THREAD to `next_trigger(delay, units)` in SC_METHOD works.

But when I tried, it does not work. I am trying to build adder module with 2 ns output delay. Instead of having a 2 ns output delay, the adder output is getting updated every 2 ns.

Design:

```
#include "systemc.h"

#define WIDTH  4

SC_MODULE(adder) {
  sc_in<sc_uint<WIDTH> > A, B;  
  sc_out<sc_uint<WIDTH> > OUT;
 
  void add(){
    sc_time t1 = sc_time_stamp();
    int current_time  = t1.value();
    int intermediate = A.read() + B.read();
    next_trigger(2, SC_NS);
    OUT.write(intermediate);
    cout << " SC_METHOD add triggered at "<<sc_time_stamp() <<endl; 
  }
  
  
  SC_CTOR(adder){
    SC_METHOD(add);
    sensitive << A << B;  
  }
};
```

I know how to simulate delay using 2 techniques: `sc_event` and `SC_METHOD` and the `wait` statement in `SC_THREAD`, but I would like to simulate the delay using next_trigger(). I have read the Language Reference Manual, but could not figure how to do it.

Simulated on EDA Playground here: https://edaplayground.com/x/dFzc

I think I need to trigger 2 NS after the inputs change, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to track state manually:

```
sc_uint<WIDTH> intermediate;

void add(){
    if (A->event() || B->event() || sc_delta_count() == 0) {
        intermediate = A.read() + B.read();
        next_trigger(2, SC_NS);
    } else {
        OUT->write(intermediate);
    }
}
```

The problem is that using `next_trigger` doesn't magically transform your `SC_METHOD` into `SC_THREAD`. In general, I find any usage of `next_trigger` inconvenient and there are better ways of doing this using `sc_event`.

Comment: I tried doing it without the bool changing variable here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68110640/12311164 I'm new to SystemC. Can you check if both codes are equivalent? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, I had different code initially, but this value became redundant after few changes. I will remove both of them.

Comment: @ShashankVM Updated to check for `sc_delta_count() == 0` to also handle initialization case.